# "got an unexpected keyword argument 'ticket_id'"

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a project management app. A project can have tickets, which are tied to the project and in the template below a project is rendered, as well as the project's tickets.

However, I get an error with the code below and I can't figure out what it means and how to solve it:

```
Exception Value:    show_ticket() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ticket_id'
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 20
```

What can be wrong?

**project template:**

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
    <span>{{ ticket }}</span>
    <a href="{% url show_ticket project.id ticket.id %}">Show ticket</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/ticket/(?P<ticket_id>\d+)/$', 'project_app.views.show_ticket', name="show_ticket"),
```

**view:**

```
@login_required
def show_ticket(request, project_id):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk = ticket_id)

    return render(request, 'projects/show_ticket.html', {"ticket" : ticket})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `show_ticket` view only accepts one variable - the project id. You are calling the reverse on that view with two variables - `project.id` and `ticket.id`.

Your URL for the view is already setup to accept the `ticket_id`, so you just need to change your view to accept the `ticket_id` as well:

```
def show_ticket(request, project_id, ticket_id):
    ....
```